# Formatting an array value inside a Heredoc

Tags: php, arrays, heredoc

I was wondering why I can't do something like `{number_format($row['my_number'])}` inside a Heredoc. Is there any way around this without having to resort to defining a variable like `$myNumber` below?

Looked at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc but found nothing.

CODE

```
foreach ($dbh -> query($sql) as $row):
    $myNumber = number_format($row['my_number']);

    $table .= <<<EOT
          <tr>
          <td>{$row['my_number']}</td> // WORKS
          <td>$myNumber</td> // WORKS
          <td>{number_format($row['my_number'])}</td> // DOES NOT WORK!
          </tr>
EOT;
endforeach;
```

Comment: @KingCrunch obviously yes, the OP did try. See the code example above.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It's a reasonable question, and the OP posted an example, plus consulted and linked to the relevant language documentation.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski You must be new here :)

Comment: @e2-e4 Uhmm, in November 2011 I was.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski and a great sense of humor!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can execute functions in a HEREDOC string by using `{$` variable expressions. You however need to define a variable for the function name beforehand:

```
$number_format = "number_format";

$table .= <<<EOT
      <tr>
      <td>{$row['my_number']}</td> // WORKS
      <td>$myNumber</td> // WORKS
      <td>{$number_format($row['my_number'])}</td> // DOES NOT WORK!
      </tr>
```

So this kind of defeats the HEREDOCs purpose of terseness.

---

For readability it might be even more helpful to define a generic/void function name like `$expr = "htmlentities";` for this purpose. Then you can utilize almost any complex expression and all global functions in heredoc or doublequotes:

```
    "   <td>  {$expr(number_format($num + 7) . ':')}  </td>  "
```

And I think `{$expr(` is just more obvious to anyone who comes across such a construct. (Otherwise it's just an odd workaround.)