# Insert php and html into div in php variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a php variable as such:

```
$output_map[$the_ID]['map'] = '<div class="marker" data-lat="'.$get_google_map['lat'].'"></div>';
```

I want the code below inside the "marker" div that's within the above var:

```
<p><?php echo $location['address']; ?></p>
<p><?php the_field('description'); ?></p>
```

The `<<<EOD` method isn't working and going in/out of php tags doesn't seem to work. It seems like it's going to look messy, I wondering what is the syntax I'm missing here?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot include that code inside the variable with the other html?

Comment: Change `the_field` to `get_field` and then just concatenate it in, like your already doing.

Comment: Oh, is `the_field()` some wordpress thing? Then nevermind... I'm out.

Comment: It is unclear what you're requesting. Show us the resulting code that you want to have in the end.

Comment: Yes @LawrenceCherone that is how I'm doing it. `the_field` is a wordpress thing yes (using Advanced custom fields), but it's kind of redundant as I can't even get the plain `echo` to show up on my site.

Comment: Most probably you have an error which you don't see because it's not showing on screen. Put this two lines before your code in order to see the eventual raised errors: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` followed by `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. Then give us feedback.

Comment: Thanks @aendeerei that did help. I had undefined vars, but ultimately Lawrence's code does work, I had some confusion with the syntax. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Important is that your code it's working now. You should accept the answer of @LawrenceCherone then, so that other users can benefit from it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$output_map[$the_ID]['map'] = '
<div class="marker" data-lat="'.$get_google_map['lat'].'">
    <p>'.$location['address'].'</p>
    <p>'.get_field('description').'</p>
</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

- Activate error reporting for showing eventual errors.
- Make use of the PHP's [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function to build your final result in an elegant manner.
- Echo the output as usual, or by using the [heredoc syntax: <<<](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). In the case of the latter I am wondering why would you choose to do it?

Notice the use of the curly brackets `{` and `}` inside the heredoc output. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280360/formatting-an-array-value-inside-a-heredoc) and *Example #3 Heredoc string quoting example* in the [heredoc syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Good luck.

```
<?php

// Display eventual errors and exceptions.
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); // SET IT TO 0 ON A LIVE SERVER!

// Dummy test function
function the_field($name) {
    return 'Some ' . $name . ' value';
}

// Dummy test values.
$the_ID = 1;
$get_google_map['lat'] = '50.2341234';
$location['address'] = 'Some address';

// Build the map item's content.
$output_map[$the_ID]['map'] = sprintf(
        '<div class="marker" data-lat="%s">
            <p>%s</p>
            <p>%s</p>
        </div>'
        , $get_google_map['lat']
        , $location['address']
        , the_field('description')
);

// Option 1.
//echo $output_map[$the_ID]['map'];

// ... or Option 2.
echo <<<MAP
    {$output_map[$the_ID]['map']}
MAP;
```

###Output (visible with "View page source" in browser, or similar option):###

```
<div class="marker" data-lat="50.2341234">
    <p>Some address</p>
    <p>Some description value</p>
</div>
```